# PlayFramework cannot connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework, rds

I have a Play application deployed on EC2 but it cannot connect to RDS. I tried to connect directly from ec2 instance using psql console and it works, so groups and everything should be set correctly. It alse means that username and password are correct. I think that problem is in database url but I'm not sure how it should look.

My current config:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://x-domain.123abc.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database_name"
slick.dbs.default.db.user="user-name"
slick.dbs.default.db.password="password"
```

Error messgae:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[SQLTransientConnectionException: db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1004ms.]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with by disabling connectionPool.

Just added to config:

```
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionPool = "disabled"
```